# Joining Rows in a Single Table With Unwanted Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sorting, ssms

Please be patient with me, I am self-taught so I am still learning and unclear on all the verbiage.

I have the following table:

```
Table (History h)
| Source ID | Action            | Created Date |
|  1        | Standard Filed    | 1/5/2021     |
|  2        | Standard Filed    | 1/7/2021     |
|  1        | Standard Reviewed | 1/7/2021     |
|  3        | Standard Filed    | 1/10/2021    |
|  4        | Standard Filed    | 1/15/2021    |
|  5        | Standard Filed    | 1/17/2021    |
|  4        | Standard Reviewed | 1/17/2021    |
|  1        | CPR Filed         | 1/18/2021    |
|  1        | CPR Reviewed      | 1/20/2021    |
|  3        | Standard Reviewed | 1/21/2021    |
|  2        | Standard Reviewed | 2/1/2021     |
|  5        | Standard Reviewed | 2/1/2021     |
```

The results that I want are:

```
|Source ID | Filed Date | Reviewed Date | Difference |
|  1       | 1/5/2021   | 1/7/2021      | 2          |
|  1       | 1/18/2021  | 1/20/2021     | 2          |
|  2       | 1/7/2021   | 2/1/2021      | 25         |   
|  3       | 1/10/2021  | 1/21/2021     | 11         |   
|  4       | 1/15/2021  | 1/17/2021     | 2          | 
|  5       | 1/17/2021  | 2/1/2021      | 15         |
```

I then want to take those results and get the average of all the differences. So on average how long does it take standard or CPR items to go from filed to review.

So the average for the above example is 9.5

My current query language is:

```sql
SELECT t1.SOURCE_ID, t1.CREATED_DATE AS 'Reviewed Date', t2.CREATED_DATE AS 'Filed Date', (DateDiff(hour,t2.CREATED_DATE,t1.CREATED_DATE)/24) AS 'Difference' 
    FROM ((SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE FROM HISTORY AS h 
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Standard Reviewed' OR h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'CPR Reviewed') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t1 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT h.SOURCE_ID, h.CHANGE_VALUE_FROM, h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO, h.CREATED_DATE FROM HISTORY as h 
WHERE (h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'Standard Filed' OR h.CHANGE_VALUE_TO = 'CPR Filed') AND (h.CREATED_DATE  >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000')) AS t2 ON (t1.SOURCE_ID = t2.SOURCE_ID) AND (t1.CREATED_DATE >= t2.CREATED_DATE))
ORDER BY SOURCE_ID ASC;
```

My results are:

```
|SOURCE_ID| Filed Date | Reviewed Date | Difference |
|  1      | 1/5/2021   | 1/7/2021      | 2          |
|  *1     | 1/5/2021   | 1/20/2021     | 15         |
|  1      | 1/18/2021  | 1/20/2021     | 2          |
|  2      | 1/7/2021   | 2/1/2021      | 25         |
|  3      | 1/10/2021  | 1/21/2021     | 11         |
|  4      | 1/15/2021  | 1/17/2021     | 2          | 
|  5      | 1/17/2021  | 2/1/2021      | 15         |
```

The average for the above data is 10.28.

So there is one row that is showing up that should not be. I have marked it with an asterisk.

Any help, another idea on how to do it, anything really, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the look of that query, you have significantly overly complicated the problem. Sample data and expected results will really help us help you, along with a description of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify! [mcve]

Comment: @Larnu I have tried to do what you suggested. Is this better?

Comment: Where does `2/1/2021` come from for `Source ID=2` and why `Source ID=4` is missing in your expected results?

Comment: @forpas Thanks for pointing that out! In my attempt to simplify I missed entering in some data. The 2/1/2021 comes from the first table where source id 2 was reviewed on 2/1/2021. Did me adding data to the tables clear up your questions? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT h1.Source_ID, h1.Created_Date Filed_Date,
       MIN(h2.Created_Date) Reviewed_Date,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, h1.Created_Date, MIN(h2.Created_Date)) / 24 Difference
FROM History h1 INNER JOIN History h2
ON h2.Source_ID = h1.Source_ID AND h2.Created_Date > h1.Created_Date
AND ((h1.Action = 'Standard Filed' AND h2.Action = 'Standard Reviewed') 
  OR (h1.Action = 'CPR Filed' AND h2.Action = 'CPR Reviewed'))
WHERE h1.Created_Date >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'  
GROUP BY h1.Source_ID, h1.Created_Date
```

To get the average difference create a CTE with the above query and aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT h1.Source_ID, h1.Created_Date Filed_Date,
         MIN(h2.Created_Date) Reviewed_Date,
         DATEDIFF(HOUR, h1.Created_Date, MIN(h2.Created_Date)) / 24 Difference
  FROM History h1 INNER JOIN History h2
  ON h2.Source_ID = h1.Source_ID AND h2.Created_Date > h1.Created_Date
  AND ((h1.Action = 'Standard Filed' AND h2.Action = 'Standard Reviewed') 
    OR (h1.Action = 'CPR Filed' AND h2.Action = 'CPR Reviewed'))
  WHERE h1.Created_Date >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000'  
  GROUP BY h1.Source_ID, h1.Created_Date   
)
SELECT AVG(1.0 * Difference) average_difference
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cc120f1a9b49c3e5057261f7988de40a).

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!! I cannot say thank you enough for your help with this!!!